# Fundamental group of the complement of Borromean rings

Tags: algebraic-topology

I got a homework asking me to show the fundamental group of the complement of the Borromean rings (say, $S^3\setminus B$ where $B$ is the Borromean rings)
I know there should be three generators, but I had a hard time to find the relations;
I know In the case of two unlinked circles, the commutator is 1;

[image]Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: I remember Hatcher has wrote a algebraic topology, the first chapter of that book has the result..

Comment: it says that circle C links with circle A,B in a way as $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, but I want to show that $[a,[b,c^{-1}]]=1$

Comment: I think I got it, using Wirtinger Presentation and get 6 relations, then reduce them to 3 as the form of commutators

Comment: I skip the exercise about Wirtinger... Maybe you should write the answer down.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your answer?